# How do get the list of non-mobile friendly URL of my website?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, search-results, googlebot-mobile

I have around 1,500 pages in my website. I want to know the list of non mobile friendly URL. How can I get the list of all pages, so that i can work on it, to make it mobile friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Search console has a [Mobile Usability report](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-usability) that "identifies pages on your site with usability problems for visitors on mobile devices."

As per their [help page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6101188), the report includes the following errors:

- Flash usage
- Viewport not configured
- Fixed-width viewport
- Content not sized to viewport
- Small font size

You can also test pages individually using the [Mobile-Friendly Test Tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6352293). I'd suggest running this one a couple of examples of each "type" of page, like the homepage, category pages, product pages, content/info pages. This will give you a good idea of what sort of fixes need to be put in place site-wide.